# How to implement hold and drag feature for multi selection?

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy

Samsung phones have this feature where you can hold your finger on an item then drag it down, i can multi select items quickly like in the gif

Is there any way i can implement this feature in my apps even if it's just for Samsung devices?

> Example image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> even if it's just for samsung devices

You can implement this feature on any device. I first found this feature in Mi devices.

It is somewhat complicated. But you can use libraries for this purpose like [DragSelectRecyclerView](https://github.com/MFlisar/DragSelectRecyclerView).

Add following code to your **build.gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.MFlisar:DragSelectRecyclerView:0.3'
}
```

In your java file, add following code:

Create a touch listener.

```
mDragSelectTouchListener = new DragSelectTouchListener()
.withSelectListener(onDragSelectionListener)
// following is all optional
.withMaxScrollDistance(distance)    // default: 16;     defines the speed of the auto scrolling
.withTopOffset(toolbarHeight)       // default: 0;      set an offset for the touch region on top of the RecyclerView
.withBottomOffset(toolbarHeight)    // default: 0;      set an offset for the touch region on bottom of the RecyclerView
.withScrollAboveTopRegion(enabled)  // default: true;   enable auto scrolling, even if the finger is moved above the top region
.withScrollBelowTopRegion(enabled)  // default: true;   enable auto scrolling, even if the finger is moved below the top region
.withDebug(enabled);
```

Attach this touch listener to the `RecyclerView`.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(mDragSelectTouchListener);
```

On item long press, inform the listener to start the drag selection.

```
mDragSelectTouchListener.startDragSelection(position);
```

Use the `DragSelectionProcessor`, it implements the above mentioned interface and can be set up with 4 modes:

1. `Simple`: simply selects each item you go by and unselects on move back
2. `ToggleAndUndo`: toggles each items original state, reverts to the original state on move back
3. `FirstItemDependent`: toggles the first item and applies the same state to each item you go by and applies inverted state on move back
4. `FirstItemDependentToggleAndUndo`: toggles the item and applies the same state to each item you go by and reverts to the original state on move back

Provide a `ISelectionHandler` in it's constructor and implement these functions:

```
onDragSelectionListener = new DragSelectionProcessor(new DragSelectionProcessor.ISelectionHandler() {
    @Override
    public Set<Integer> getSelection() {
        // return a set of all currently selected indizes
        return selection;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSelected(int index) {
        // return the current selection state of the index
        return selected;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateSelection(int start, int end, boolean isSelected, boolean calledFromOnStart) {
        // update your selection
        // range is inclusive start/end positions
        // and the processor has already converted all events according to it'smode
    }
})
// pass in one of the 4 modes, simple mode is selected by default otherwise
.withMode(DragSelectionProcessor.Mode.FirstItemDependentToggleAndUndo);
```

You can see a demo activity [here](https://github.com/MFlisar/DragSelectRecyclerView/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/com/michaelflisar/dragselectrecyclerview/demo/MainActivity.java).

Is there any other library for the same purpose?

Yes, you can also use [Drag Select Recycler View](https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview) by **afollestad**. And you can see practical implementation for afollestad's Drag select Recycler View [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWMblVhrgqk).

Comment: Hi, could you by chance know a way how to select the items without having to long press and drag, but activate the "drag select" with a button instead and then simply slide on the items as it is in Google Photos app. Thanks!